# on hover animate the background image but not the text on top

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am bit stuck at some point.So on hover over the background image grows bigger.But if I put a text on that image then animation doesn't work quite well.Let me show you my code

HTML

```
<div class="resize">
    <a id="apply" href="" target="_blank">
        <!--<h1 class="grow">Search & Apply</h1>-->
        <img class="title" src="images/search_inactive1.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.title').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({ width: "+=40",height: "+=40",top: "-=20",left: "-=20"}, 130);                             
}, 
function(){
    $(this).animate({ width: "-=40",height: "-=40",top: "+=20",left: "+=20"}, 200);                      
});
```

CSS

```
.resize img {
    position: relative;
    width: 110px;
}
```

Is there any way to tell jquery not to animate the text and just only the background image.

Thanks in advance.

JSfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/jHeDQ/3/

Comment: Please add a jsFiddle, thus it's easier for us to help you.

Comment: Do you mean the text in the h1 tag?  Because its commented out...

Comment: Thanks Stefan.jsfiddle link is added.

Comment: I have added the text on the image.But when you mouseover the text the animation is not working 100% correctly.

Comment: @Pattle yes i have removed the comment.

Comment: If you remove the parts that don't work from the fiddle, people will have trouble figuring out what you want. I know I am.

Comment: @Dom..I have removed the comment not the 'parts'

Comment: it's working fine for me, text isn't changing

Comment: @PatsyIssa Did you check the updated fiddle.If you mouseover the text then the image doesn't grow bigger and the animation looks bit weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your selector on the container not the image alone, as the text is positioned over it,

```
$('.resize)
```

Instead of

```
$('.title')
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jHeDQ/5/)

==== Edit====

For further clarification the .stop() method was used in order to avoid playing the animation every time the mouse enters and exits resulting in a "broken" animation.

The .find() method was used to find the children with the class .title.

Comment: @Patsy Issa I would add `.stop(true, true)` to your code to prevent infinite grow/shrink of the background when mousein/out is faster than the animation...

Comment: @Patsy and tborychowski Brilliant :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can drop JavaScript (if you don't need IE<=8 support) and use css transform, e.g.:

```
.resize .title { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 110px; 
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.resize:hover .title { transform: scale(1.3); }
```

[full fiddle-example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jHeDQ/6/)

Comment: Thanks tborychowski.That's excellent.Actually I have accepted Patsy's answer.Sorry :)